# Displaying "alert" messages in Twitter Bootstrap rails Carousel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems, alert, carousel

I am using Twitter Bootstrap rails Carousel for a survey project. I need to add a feature where if user doesnot answer a question and try to click next arrow should be shown a message "please choose an answer before proceeding".. how do I accomplish this? is it by alert message?  how do I do this?

Comment: **how do I do this?** You should show us your html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".carousel-next").on("click",function(){
if(condition){ // condition -> doesnot answer a question
    alert('message'); 
    return false;
}
```

});

```
  $(".carousel-prev").on("click",function(){
    if($(".carousel-inner .item.active").index() == 0){
        return false;
    }
  });
```